# VisualStateManager with Windows Phone 8.1 BottomAppBar

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, visualstatemanager, appbar, commandbar

I'm using VisualStateManager in a Windows 8.1 app to update the visibility of buttons on the BottomAppBar...

However this same XAML appears to not be supported for the BottomAppBar on Windows Phone 8.1.

When I attempt to update a button in Blend I get the error: An animation is trying to modify an object named '', but no such object can be found in the PageStandIn.

Is there a way to make this work or will I have to use code-behind to toggle the visibility manually?
is there any way to make this work so I can share the code from win81 to update the command bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AppBars are very special, they are part of the System UI (in some sense) and thus somethings tend not work as expected.

Using storyboards don't work for updating them.
You can use the code behind, but if you are using an MVVM framework you should be able to `Bind` them to a Boolean and using a [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/758656/Use-Converters-in-your-Windows-Phone-Apps) to do the visibility management.

#### Model

```
public bool ShowAppButton {get; set;}
```

#### View

```
<AppBarButton x:Name="MyAppButton" Label="AppButton" Visibility="{Binding ShowAppButton, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks I remember this issue from wp7 but I thought they updated this in 8.1 to not use the shell so you could do stuff like this, guess I was wrong! I wanted storyboards because I'm showing/hiding based on interaction not a value that I can bind... but at least I know for sure, thanks!

Comment: they did fix somethings at least, I don't know what MVVM frameworks this was broken on, but you could not do Binding in Caliburn in WP8, but now you can in WP8.1. So getting there :D

Comment: i do remember not being able to bind so yes indeed you're right about it being better! in fact I just tested this in win10 mobile and it does work with the visual states, so there's that too :) thanks again for your help